# Connection timeout accessing PHP script from Android browser

Tags: php, android, wamp

I can't access a single php script from my android device browser using “192.168.x.x/image.php”. It says

> connection timed out

192.168.x.x is the ip of my PC. The same works if I try through my laptop browser.
My wamp server is online (green).

Comment: Please post in a normal way. Put all info in the body. Questions to. The subject should only be used as subject.

Comment: @greensapps I'll take that into consideration :)

Comment: @greenapps could suggest something if you have understood the question

Comment: There is no question. And you did not seem it necessary to edit your post.

Comment: the wamp server and laptop browser are on the same machine?
Maybe try to disable windows firewall or antivirus or try access the php  using your PC wan ip.

Comment: @Tse Ka leong yes! I had to add rule for port80 in firewall. Also had to make some changes in httpd.config. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your adndroid device must have to in same network. 
Check your device network and Your PC network.

Comment: I am using connectify software to create wifi environment from my laptop. so both are on same network.

Comment: Please put that info in your post. Why do you need connectivity software? Please explain (in your post). You work without a router? Is this linux?

Comment: I resolved the problem.The image is getting tranferred now, I had to make some changes in httpd.conf and also add rule in firewall for port 80.I am working in windows 8.